# Was the Isp = 11,000 seconds Neumann Drive tested on the ISS? Did it work? How well did it perform?

Tags: iss, propulsion, ion-thruster, testing, electric-propulsion

In 2018 answers were posted to

- [What is Australia's Bartolomeo platform? When does it arrive at the ISS; when and where will it be attached?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27196/12102)
- [Will the Neumann drive start testing aboard the ISS some time in 2018?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27185/12102) <sup>1</sup>

indicating that "Bartolomeo is not Australian but European" but that it will be "installed on the Airbus DS Bartolomeo platform as part of the FAST mission (Facility for Australian Space Testing) **in mid-2019.**"

See also

- [Which way will the Neumann drive (on the ISS) point, what will be its maximum possible thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27201/12102)

**Question:** Was the Isp = 11,000 seconds Neumann Drive tested on the ISS? Did it work? How well did it perform?

---

<sup>1</sup> cites the 2016 Daily Mail article [Radical ion rocket engine that could 'get to Mars and back on one tank of fuel' set to be tested on the ISS](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3825943/Radical-ion-rocket-engine-Mars-one-tank-fuel-set-tested-ISS.html)

Comment: There's nothing about it on the ISS daily reports or even the company's own website.

Comment: There may be something in this but the Daily Mail is not a reliable source of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick Neumann told me they had to raise a bunch of cash in order to pay for ride and slot on the Airbus/ESA Bartolomeo module for the ISS. I suspect they weren't able to do it in time and had to find other ways to perform a flight demonstration.

See https://neumannspace.com/the-spirit-mission-is-a-go/ which describes their scheduled first flight on a 6U demonstrator CubeSat in 2022.

In terms of very high ISP, they've got competition from [MagDrive](https://www.magdrivespace.com/) which just raised $2M from [Founders Fund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founders_Fund) for a similar technology.

- https://theoxfordmagazine.com/news/magdrive-secures-1-4m-seed-funding-for-new-propulsion-system/
- https://techcrunch.com/2020/12/17/magdrive-secures-seed-funding-for-new-propulsion-system-which-could-take-us-to-the-stars/