# Would ISS raise up with the help of the self-powered ion thrusters?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, ion-thruster

The solar arrays provide [about 100 k](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/structure/elements/solar_arrays-about.html)W of power, so we can put the two [HiPEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Power_Electric_Propulsion) thusters providing 1 N (1000 mN) power combined, with the specific impulse as high as 6000–9000. Such an acceleration force for 419,700 kg mass does not look very good for meeting any possible timelines and deadlines of gaining velocity.

Still, would the 1 N force be sufficient to start raising the orbit, or atmospheric drag is more even at that altitude?

Comment: somewhat different but related: [Will the ISS have electric propulsion to maintain altitude? Is there enough power for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19816/12102)
as well as [Will the Neumann drive start testing aboard the ISS some time in 2018?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27185/12102)
and also [Which way will the Neumann drive (on the ISS) point, what will be its maximum possible thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27201/12102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, according to multiple sources, including [the answer to this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/what-is-the-iss-drag).  The estimated drag forces on the ISS, on average, appear to be about 0.25N (although [some estimates](https://www.wired.com/2013/04/air-resistance-in-orbit/) put it as high as 0.9N).  So yes, in theory, a constant thrust could do it.  Now, you'd have to contend with the power drain.  I believe HiPEP thrusters use somewhere in the range of 25-50KW, so you'd max out the power on the ISS just keeping it in orbit, which kind of nullifies the point of having it there in the first place...

Comment: I've got to wonder if the estimated life of those thrusters would be lowered if you planned to fire it 24/7 over long periods of time as well. Given that they're meant to be doing long, low-impulse thrusts I'd don't know if it would matter; but I don't think they were ever planned to be doing many year-long impulses.

Comment: Fair, and they've never been used in space AFAIK, so we can't really say for sure.  But previous ion powered spacecraft have had crazy long burn times (think Dawn) and they ended up just fine after those long thrust times.  Plus redundancy and load sharing might help a lot there

Comment: [This picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Dawn_trajectory_as_of_September_2009.png) makes it seem like there was not 100% constant thrust for Dawn.  Then again, some of those blue sections would still be an impressive amount of time. Thanks regardless, the Dawn page helped clear up some misconceptions I was having about how Ion thrusters are used in practice :)!

Comment: Indeed.  Apparently Dawn's total mission thrusting time was 5.9 years (although I'm certain it wasn't all at once, it's still amazing what the thrusters could do)

Comment: The ISS spends a significant fraction of its time in darkness. It's somewhat less than 50% and as it's highly inclined orbit precesses there are periods with no eclipse, but overall it's a big effect.